# Почему компиляторы не могут оптимизировать цикл для std::string?

Tags: c++, строки, ассемблер, оптимизация, utf-8

Почему `gcc` и `clang` оптимизируют цикл в `memset` для `std::u8string`, но не для `std::string`? Неужели они считают, что по `char&` можно изменить `N`? Значит ли это, что с точки зрения производительности UTF-8 строки лучше хранить в `std::u8string`, а не в `std::string`?

[Diff для gcc и clang в Compiler Explorer.](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEAtydwAZAiZsADk/ACNsUhAAdnIAB3QlYhcmL19/QNT0zKEwiOi2OITkh2wnLJEiFlIiHL8AoOraoXrGohKo2Pik%2Bwamlrz2kd7w/vLBxIBKe3QfUlROLksAZnDUXxwAajNNjyUiUnDgI9wzLQBBG9uAN3QCTH3UJHQUiHCifcjyPtTpgQCBTucTECzvNDokbHd9oj9oJSPsfsJ9gRDpsACL7LRHKyY/ZgMBHPGRQmHay2Agwsxwh5I5lQ0hmACsVgIHLx5PxhKZSIZOIewq4i3o3HZ/ACXB05HQ3A8tlsQOWq2w1M2fHIRG04sWAGsQOytIZuNJ%2BGwQNJ2QA6LTs9mbABs7IsAA4XYlpF6PeRZfLFVx%2BEoQGa9XLxeQ4LAUBgcPhiGRKNQ6IxWBxuDrBMIxBJODI5MJlGpNFHyPogkYTGgVdZ7NhHM5XBB3GM2uzgkxMH0yhUbQUMi3st5WoEu2lh1k%2BwMErIOiPuqMx%2BMu4u6pNZ7N58Meh2J3umtuB9JFkp1WtuFsdntNUcTmcLldRXdnq93p9vr9/oDgaCfA9cELlZelGQRJEUTRH8sT5AlNiJLFST5SkEOpGxrDpWF4VuFkkXBDkuR5bE8XgnDmWFUVEhxaNJS4aUA31BUlXrIkLxWNYtQsfhIx0eZFiQbAWBwBIIAlC0rRtF07QsHgXVtR1nS0RJNk2f1A34YNQ3DXV9UWWNkDQdA2BSBh4lTCAMBMsyEmAHhZIEBgiHiMMIBiJiYnCRoAE9s34KyOGEAB5Jh6F8iscDYYxgEkCKCFIGpnEebAwwrbB1BqHxnL8yhhCbJj6AIGJSB8rwcCYp9rV4aMaCMYAlAANQIbAAHcgpSZgctzURxEkItutLDQmP0HhDGiusaQbQqYjDSBFi%2BEdUoAWmBclzEmqwLC0fYlqCzZQybRKsjcHsD1G0Jpn7QZRqnIpR1yAIbsKEcT2uxtm03fdV0e96jq6LdLrnAxTi%2Bh7gYB0ogZ4c9L0LXUEvWPhxPomUmODdQvSW%2BT9mAVBUH2ey7R4NFlQ2wEkxIVEtlG/YvGsxgqYsbV5h4vSY3jYzTIZiyrK5wZdmigB9M4fCYQ1HPoZzSFc9yK081hSHCnUAuYIgQrCpjIui2L5UIBLamS1L5XSzLsuq3LnLo%2BVppKxWyvWeVKr8xZapYeqmta9rOvN7r8z62QBpUIaK30WQa1MVjDCK2axIVFJFu4FaiEwNbWK2na9oOj7W3bb6DAuyGdwMW6RzOoc7tehJRo3f7QfHavDs6JhlymQuB2ryYy5B49AaL6Glg4zggjObBEdoqVUYrdHMexgXIQgEWxZhCBSYwux9gpsguMBOm%2BcZzYz1ZqN9I5%2BnzKoSzOZstBw%2BF0hRfF9MpZljyvMVnKVeC0Lwt17AopMHW/A9ZHUNkxE2qAspjwtvlCsNtSpYAdjxc4VUkYCDqo1ZqbUOqyhzPIP2hYA7yEGuWeU%2BhNhjVrOtNeUcZrwHmvHLIy1Vq4iobYdOu19q/SbidTwedzo9krsXZ6WQy4lxnL3duXClydz4VIz6Pc25vW7s0WRyjBH93YhqAwI8x7IwYhpZiXAMYuixtId44c0SL0NMvVethyaEEplqGmu8bJak2CzXSx92ZGTPhQC%2BvNr52Qck/Fy1BZbynlj5D%2BxlApq2/prP%2B2tEHkGAQbFKYCMoQLNjqX4MDrZFVtt5e2FVkHOzQW7DBntsFdTwb1AhxZFBBxIXofI4cJrUOmjHehCcuBJxTiwtO20OFZz%2BgENsp1ZEFxmJIsRQhRHCOKBIpRjdpF1zyA3bOzcIbTKUTIsGHcejqJhoPfIOiyl0X0WjbgxjTE4zxgTCwRMSaRw3g4reWwgi0yvgzLiHjeIGnNFwS05BrQejtIkT0PAPTSDkloHgiREgAE5pDkIMVpewOl/n8XIMaaQWg7QukRTwLQHoD6IpdKSj0iLAWcLRdwI%2BfEYyIAMhAFAhAaA0Asr7OpUhCEliaQVJAYZRr0CFeymgRBvIdR0qQIV%2BRZVKHFZK6VWg9GTyDNwHEBAOX7A9i1eI%2BwbnY1xvjQmxNHhKENTPMxJqHlEwZQC407JEV2k2CSolbotDahdDwEVEkQU2hdSiqFIaPShqhYxKe9KMURjZiytl2rOUX25QWXlDTiGCrDOQ0VirE3Ks4GaBVg4FVKqlQWtVkaNVcC1TqvVBqjVmLnsASx98l77AtVakxs8LEL1bdYh12LBLCUGLHOiwLrSmjtOyCl4aw1ztGnSkMMbPF8SNCaF1bqqVyVNN631NL1WaWjVi5G3FK2HqXce8gyVpbHWkEAA%3D%3D%3D)

Код для `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

void chop(int N, std::string str) {
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Ассемблер `gcc` для `std::string`:

```
test    edi, edi
jle     .L1
movsx   rdi, edi
xor     eax, eax
.L3:
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
mov     BYTE PTR [rdx+rax], 0
add     rax, 1
cmp     rdi, rax
jne     .L3
.L1:
ret
```

Код для `std::u8string`:

```
#include <string>

void chop(int N, std::u8string str) {
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Ассемблер `gcc` для `std::u8string`:

```
test    edi, edi
jle     .L1
mov     edx, edi
mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi]
xor     esi, esi
jmp     memset
```

Comment: Единственная разница между `char` и `char8_t` (кроме знаковости) - это то, что на первый не действует strict aliasing. Значит да, компилятор думает что или `N` или `i` может поменяться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat разве для того, чтобы считать, что `N` или `i` могут измениться, они не должны быть указателем/ссылкой?

Comment: Почему? `int i = 0; *(char*)&i = 42;` Вот мы поменяли `i` через `char`, хотя int - не указатель и не ссылка.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в том смысле, что компилятор же внутри функции может специально так выделить память для `N` и `str`, чтобы проблем с алиасингом не было, а когда адреса приходят извне функции, то не может. Или для этого надо всю строку проверять?

Comment: Хмм, да, я понял идею. Значит просто компилятор недостаточно умный.

Answer (score 8):

Согласно стандарту, `char*` (который лежит внутри `std::string`) может указывать на любой объект, в том числе и на `std::string`. И у компилятора нет никаких свидетельств обратного, потому он и вынужден генерировать код исходя из предположения, что присваивание `str[i]=0` может изменить базовый адрес строки.

В то же время, `char8_t*` не может указывать ни на какой объект кроме `char8_t` (на момент разыменования), потому для `std::u8string` таких проблем не наблюдается.

Да, это означает что `std::u8string` быстрее `std::string`, а потому предпочтительнее.

Comment: Что такое базовый адрес строки, и как присваивание `str[i]=0` может его изменить?

Comment: @wololo это место с которого строка начинается в памяти. Присваивание могло бы его изменить если бы сама структура `std::string` лежало где-то в этом месте.

Comment: Хотите сказать присваивание `str[i]=0` может изменить местоположение внутреннего буфера, в котором хранятся символы строки?

Comment: На самом деле не может, но компилятор не знает этого и вынужден учитывать такую возможность.

Comment: Похоже вы правы, и компилятор действительно предполагает, что присвоение `str[i] = 0` может модифицировать локальный объект `std::string`. Если отключить правило строгих псевдонимов опцией `-fno-strict-aliasing`, то компилятор перестаёт оптимизировать цикл в `memset`. [Ссылка на пример](https://godbolt.org/z/6G83TGoxW).